# spinnaker rbac with ldap: can't get correct role by email UserDnAttribute

Tags: rbac, spinnaker

Is that possible to login with the email address and then get the correct roles provided by ldap of the email login ? If the answer is Yes, how to configure it? Please help me, thank you guys!!!

Answer (score 0):

## Cloud Provider(s):

k8s v2

## Environment:

spinnaker 1.19.2

## Feature Area:

helm3 install

Answer (score 0):

halyard config:

```
authn:
ldap:
enabled: true
url: ldap://URL:port
userSearchBase: dc=test,dc=com
userDnPattern: mail={0},ou=Users
userSearchFilter: (&(mail={0})(employeeType=1)(|(memberOf=cn=admins,ou=Groups,dc=test,dc=com)(memberOf=cn=devs,ou=Groups,dc=test,dc=com)(memberOf=cn=tests,ou=Groups,dc=test,dc=com)))
managerDn: cn=manager,dc=test,dc=com
managerPassword: password

authz:
groupMembership:
service: LDAP
ldap:
roleProviderType: LDAP
url: ldap://URL:port/dc=test,dc=com
managerDn: cn=manager,dc=test,dc=com
managerPassword: password
userSearchBase: dc=test,dc=com
userDnPattern: cn={0},ou=Users
groupSearchBase: ou=Groups
groupSearchFilter: (uniqueMember={0})
groupRoleAttributes: cn
enabled: true
```